# Count @ in all sheets in an excel file

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

So I need to find how many @'s there are in a excel file.

My current code return IF theres a @ in the file on the 1 sheet only.
I need to find how many @ there is in total, and it should run though all sheets that exsits in the file (number/names can de different each time). Is this even possible?

```
def excel_contains_str(filename, search='@'):
    return pd.read_excel(filename).astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(search)).any().any()
```

Comment: yes, why not. It also seems like your solution works.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ but it doesn't return the number of @ it finds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution works, although on the off chance that you have hundreds of columns, searching through them all if there's a match in the 3rd column itself is a little wasteful. So, consider iterating over your columns, and short circuit your operation with the builtin `any`.

```
def excel_contains_str(filename, search='@'):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, dtype='str')
    return any(df[c].str.contains(search).any() for c in df.columns)
```

When reading in your columns, specify `dtype='str'` so they're read in as strings. This prevents the need for a subsequent `astype` call.

---

However, if you need the *number* of matches, you'll have no choice but to use an  `apply` and sum the values.

```
def excel_contains_str(filename, search='@'):
    df = pd.read_excel(filename, dtype='str')
    return df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(search)).values.sum()
```

Demo -

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A' : ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], 
    'B' : ['foo@bar.com', np.nan, 'test@baz.com'], 
    'C' : [1, 2, 1]
})
df    
     A             B  C
0  aaa   foo@bar.com  1
1  bbb           NaN  2
2  ccc  test@baz.com  1
```

```
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('@')).values.sum()
2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, what if i want to search for a whole word, like "zipcode".. as i understand it, this function will break down the word and match each character, or am i wrong?

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup It does not. Pass `search='^zipcode$'`, the regex pattern specifies full word matching. Or else, you can use `x.eq('zipcode')` in the lambda.

Comment: and its not 'x.str.eq(search)' with the '.str.'?

Comment: @RasmusBidstrup No, `eq` is not a part of the `.str` accessor family.

Answer (score 0):

To read from all of the sheets in the excel file, pass `sheet_name=None` to `read_excel`:

```
def excel_contains_str(filename, search='@'):
    return sum(
        df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(search)).values.sum()
        for name, df in pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None).items()
    )
```